# How to excecute the conditions stored in column of table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

Below I will be describing all the tables which I will be using.

The first table is the Base table on which we have to calculate the cost.

### Del_Line table

[image]

### The second Table is Outbound_Cost_Table

[image]

The third table contains the column which has a calculation for each country*city*plant_code

### Calculation Table

[image]

There can be more countries and cities with different plant codes and calculations.
What I want to do is to write the generic query to calculate the outbound cost at each delivery line since the **Calculation table** will be dynamic and can be updated by the business users at any time.

I will show you the sample query calculating the outbound cost for one city.

```
with cte as (
Select A.plant_code, B.Cost/(Sum(A.Packs)*2) cost_per_pack
from #del_line A left join Outbound_Cost B  
on A.dl_plant_code = B.Plant_code and A.city = B.City
group by A.[DL_Plant_Code],B.Cost
)

Select A.*,
      B.cost_per_pack*A.Packs*2 as Outbound_Handling_Cost
from #del_line A left join CTE B 
On  A.dl_plant_code = B.dl_plant_code
```

In this above query, I am calculating for Dallas.

Now I want to write the generic query in which I dont have to harcode for every city.

I want something like this

```
with cte as (
Select A.plant_code, C.Calc cost_per_pack
from #del_line A left join Outbound_Cost B  
on A.dl_plant_code = B.Plant_code and A.city = B.City left Join #Calc C on A.Market = C.Market and C.kpi = 'Outbound Handling'and C.kpi_level = 'Delivery Line'
group by A.[DL_Plant_Code],B.Cost
)

Select A.*,
      C.calc as Outbound_Handling_Cost
from #del_line A left join CTE B 
On  A.dl_plant_code = B.dl_plant_code left Join #Calc C on A.Market = C.Market and C.Handling = 'Outbound Handling'  and C.[KPI Level] = 'Delivery Line Drilldown'
```

Please avoid using the loop since the base table del_line is very big.

Comment: Storing an equation in a column means that you have to use dynamic SQL of some sort.  Perhaps you can find a better way to store the equation, such as storing coefficients and exponents.

Comment: The equation is dynamic, and the user at the front end can change it at any time. We will then update the table in our database from Sharepoint. So can you please explain or direction with more clarity if possible?

Comment: Some required reading: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)